# Android Studio SQLiteOpenHelper <column definition name> or <table constraint> expected, got 'no'

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, cursor

```
 "CREATE TABLE " + ItemList.TABLE_NAME + "( " +
        ItemList._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
        ItemList.COLUMN_NO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_VER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_SIZE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_DATE + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_URL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemList.COLUMN_BANNER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        " );"
```

this is my SQL in android studio

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE apk( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,no INTEGER NOT NULL, suggest_text_1 TEXT NOT NULL, suggest_text_2 TEXT NOT NULL, ver TEXT NOT NULL, code INTEGER NOT NULL, size TEXT NOT NULL, date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, url INTEGER NOT NULL, image TEXT NOT NULL, banner TEXT NOT NULL,  );
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
```

and this is my error log

I don't know why this suddenly throws an error
I have never modified the database and only added the columns corresponding to the content added in PHP.
please help me solve this problem (;_;)

Comment: Remove the last `,` from the sql statement.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i missed last comma.. i think you are SOOOOOO NICE GUY